# How to apply conditional formatting in pivot table EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting, epplus

I have an ASP.NET Mvc application which generates Excel reports using EPPlus. One of the worksheet in the workbook generated contains a pivot table. I want to apply conditional formatting in the Pivot Table to color the background color of those cells having value equal to 1.

The following code is used to create Pivot Table.

```
var dataRange = _objSheet.Cells[_objSheet.Dimension.Address.ToString()];
_objSheet = outputExcel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Pivot");
var ptTable = _objSheet.PivotTables.Add(_objSheet.Cells["A1"], dataRange, "PivotTable");
ptTable.GridDropZones = true;
ptTable.ApplyPatternFormats = true;
ptTable.Compact = false;
ptTable.CompactData = false;
ptTable.Indent = 0;
ptTable.RowGrandTotals = false;
ptTable.ColumnGrandTotals = false;
ptTable.ShowMemberPropertyTips = false;
ptTable.DataOnRows = false;
ptTable.UseAutoFormatting = false;
```

How do i apply Conditional Formatting to the Range of Pivot Table ??

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but requires a hack with the XML since it seems epplus does not currently support the `Pivot` property on `ConditionalFormatting`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.conditionalformatting.pivot?view=openxml-2.8.1

So, if you have a pivot table and add the formatting, you can set the flag so Excel associates it with the Pivot table in the worksheet.  For example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Pivot_Table_Conditional_Format()
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359688/how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-in-pivot-table-epplus
    //Throw in some data
    var dt = new DataTable("tblData");
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Group", typeof (string)),
        new DataColumn("MValue", typeof (int)),
        new DataColumn("Month", typeof (int)),
        new DataColumn("String", typeof (object))
    });

    var rnd = new Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        //This adds some randomness to the number of groups that will be created
        row[0] = $"Group {rnd.Next(1, 100)}";
        row[1] = i * rnd.Next(1, 100);

        //This adds randomness to the columns so not guaranteed to be all 12
        row[2] = rnd.Next(1, 12);
        row[3] = Path.GetRandomFileName();

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Pivot_Table_Conditional_Format.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var wsData = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
        wsData.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

        var wsPivot = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Pivot");

        var pivotTable1 = wsPivot.PivotTables.Add(
            wsPivot.Cells["A1"]
            , wsData.Cells[1, 1, wsData.Dimension.End.Row, wsData.Dimension.End.Column]
            , "DataPivot"
        );

        pivotTable1.DataFields.Add(pivotTable1.Fields["MValue"]);

        //Grouping will be by the "Group" column
        pivotTable1.RowFields.Add(pivotTable1.Fields["Group"]);

        //Columns will be months
        pivotTable1.ColumnFields.Add(pivotTable1.Fields["Month"]);

        //Set conditional formatting but have to determine the range in the pivot table
        var groups = dt
            .Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(row => row["Group"])
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        var columns = dt
            .Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(row => row["Month"])
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        var colOffset = pivotTable1.FirstDataCol;
        var groupOffset = pivotTable1.FirstDataRow + pivotTable1.FirstHeaderRow;

        var range = new ExcelAddress
        (
            pivotTable1.Address.Start.Row + groupOffset
            , pivotTable1.Address.Start.Column + colOffset
            , groups.Count + groupOffset
            , columns.Count + colOffset
        );

        var cond = wsPivot.ConditionalFormatting.AddGreaterThanOrEqual(range);
        cond.Formula = "100";
        cond.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.Black;
        cond.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        cond.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Yellow;

        //Only way to set the pivot table as the target is with XML Hack
        var parent = cond.Node.ParentNode;
        var doc = parent.OwnerDocument;

        //Need an attribute "pivot" with a value of "1" (true)
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.conditionalformatting.pivot?view=openxml-2.8.1
        var att = doc.CreateAttribute("pivot", doc.NamespaceURI);
        att.Value = "1";
        parent.Attributes.Append(att);

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

which gives this:

[image]